# How to protect VIP contacts?

Tags: salesforce-classic

I would like to know how do you manage VIP contacts and more specifically communications to them. We are afraid that through various reports, VIPs could be mass-added to a communication campaign. Our settings is as follow: Salesforce is linked to ExactTarget Marketing Cloud.
We would like to make sure that only our director can send them communications. Is there a way to implement a workflow to allow communication to go out (though ExactTarget)?

I thought of ticking the email opt-out box, but that would just prevent anyone from communicating with them. I also thought about a different record type, but that could lead to duplicated contacts if a standard user re-create that contact. Because the kick is that in the case where one of our department is already in contact with that VIP, then communication are allowed.

I'm not sure if my description is very clear, but that the settings we have.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think this post may be of interest to you. Especially the last comment:

> The only way to restrict access is to set records to private in the sharing settings, the only people who would then be able to access a record are:
>   the owner,
>   Anyone above them in the role hierarchy,
>   Administrators,
>   Users that have been shared the record manually,
>   users as per sharing rules.

https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000grAwAAI

Comment: RecordTypes donot control visibility.

Comment: You're right Amit. I'm sorry. I'll change my answer.